# C# - Add GroupLayer to Active Map (ArcGIS Pro)

Tags: arcgis-pro, c#, feature-layer, group-layer

I'm trying to add a groupLayer to active map using C# and ArcGIS Pro. Devloping a plugin.

This is my sample code or what I've tried so far:

```
Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.Map myMap = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.Map();

Esri.ArcGISRuntime.UI.Controls.MapView mapView = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.UI.Controls.MapView();

            Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.Basemap myBasemap = myMap.Basemap;

            LayerCollection myLayerCollection = myBasemap.BaseLayers;

            var am = Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Security.AuthenticationManager.Current;
            am.AddCredential(new ArcGISNetworkCredential(wmts + "?", user.Email, user.Password)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user.Email, user.Password),
            });

            var uri = new Uri(wmts + "?");

            WmtsService myWmtsService = new WmtsService(uri);

            // Load the WMTS service.
            await myWmtsService.LoadAsync();

            // Get the service information (i.e. metadata) about the WMTS service.
            WmtsServiceInfo myWmtsServiceInfo = myWmtsService.ServiceInfo;

            // Obtain the read only list of WMTS layer info objects, and select the one with the desired Id value.
            WmtsLayerInfo info = myWmtsServiceInfo.LayerInfos.Single<WmtsLayerInfo>(l => l.Id == "default");

            // Create a WMTS layer using WMTS layer info.
            WmtsLayer myWmtsLayer = new WmtsLayer(info);

            //myLayerCollection.Add(myWmtsLayer);

            Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.FeatureLayer newLayer = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.FeatureLayer(uri);

            Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.GroupLayer gLayer = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Mapping.GroupLayer();
            gLayer.Name = "Footprint";
            gLayer.Layers.Add(newLayer);

            await gLayer.LoadAsync();

            mapView.Map = myMap;

            mapView.Map.OperationalLayers.Add(gLayer);

            await newLayer.LoadAsync();
```

This group layer doesn't appear on active map.
Any ideas?